# Swift 4 - CodableFirebase and nested child with UID

Tags: swift, firebase, codable, decodable

I am trying to use CodableFirebase to parse a snapshot.

My Json is like this :

```
snapshot.value = Optional({
    Box =     {
        Outbox =         {
            "-LpdzdzdzdzdDs7" =             {
                DateInvoice = "2019-09-23 10:41:20 +0000";
                TrailOrHike = Hike;
                Number_of_child = 2;
                Children =                 {
                    0VZrgdYvV4hyhhyhhy4tyElASvR83 =                     {
                        DateVenue = "2019-09-23 10:43:44 +0000";
                        Age = 3;
                        "Avatar" = "gs://oooo.appspot.com/Avatar/0V3R4tyElASvR83.png";

                    };
                    wQpyIhyhyhyhyh1CI6YBfc3yppX2 =                     {
                        "Avatar" = "http://graph.facebook.com/00000/picture?type=large&height=200&width=200";
                                           };
                };
```

In my Outbox, I can have UID (of families)
And in each UID, I can have 0,1 or x children, with data inside.

I would like to parse it correctly but I don't manage to do it with dynamic UID (like -LpdzdzdzdzdDs7), and inside this dynamic UID ,there is more data to parse (Age,DateVenue,Avatar)..

I have no problem to parse other data, but when it's nested I am lost .

My Codable for the rest is simple :

```
 struct CampProfile: Codable {

        struct Family : Codable {
            let DateVenue : String?
             enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
                  case DateVenue
                   }

        }

        let Camp_Name: String
        let Camp_Adress: String

}

 let model = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(CampProfile.self, from: value)
                    print(model)
let model2 = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(CampProfile.Family.self, from: value)
                    print(model2) . //NOTWORKING
```

Comment: Are you saying your first decoding (`model`) is working?

Comment: @joakimDanielson yes,it is. All the data is the 'root' of the snapshot is correctly mapped. But when it goes to Outbox or Age, I don't manage to get it (specially when it's with dynamic child (like UID)

Comment: Have you tried to use a dictionary, `[String: Family]`, as a property?